# Oracle - CHAR(39)

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

What is the equivalent syntax in Oracle:

```
SELECT CHAR(39) --this displays an apostrophe on the screen
```

I have spent some time Googling this; this afternoon.  I have tried: CHR(39); ASCII(39) etc.  I thought this would be easy to find but it was not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT CHR(39) FROM DUAL
```

Every SELECT needs a FROM in Oracle. DUAL is a table with a single cell in it that is used in cases where you just want to build a row of values yourself. Any table containing a single row would work the same way.

Comment: Thanks.  That's it.  I will accept in ten minutes when the time limit expires.  +1.